# System programming with C(Time interval)

Tags: borland-c

I am new to system programming. I am trying to print time interval using the `puts()` function, but I am getting errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <DOS.h>
#include <BIOS.h>

unsigned long int far *time = (unsigned long int far*) 0x0040006C;

void main()
{
    unsigned long int tx;
    tx = (*time);
    tx = tx +18;
    puts("Before");
    while((*time) <= tx);
    puts("After");
}
```

Error Screenshot:

[image]

PS: I am using Borland C compiler, and DOSBox to run these programs.

Comment: Error Screenshot:      http://imgur.com/a/jpa0o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your screenshot you're trying to `puts` an int, which only takes `char*`.

Try this instead of `puts(tx)`

```
printf("%d", tx);
```